# How to determine the standard normal loss function L(z)

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have a standard normal distribution table with 4 columns. One of the rows looks like this:

```
z f01(z) F01(z) L(z)
2.42 0.0213 0.9922 0.0026
```

I know that i can use `qnorm(0.9922)`to get the z-value (2.42), but now I need a function to get the `L(z)`-value based on the z-value. What function can I use to achieve this?

EDIT: what i was looking for L(z) is in fact called the standard normal loss function. Thanks @GavinKelly for this hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can easily help you, if you give as a definition of L(.).
Ok, let's believe the answer by Gavin Kelly.

In that case,

```
L0 <- function(x) exp(-(x^2)/2)/sqrt(2*pi) - x * (1 - pnorm(x))
L <- function(x) dnorm(x) - x * pnorm(x, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

is a numerically better, namely accurate also for large `x`,  where `L0` suffers from cancellation:

```
 > L(10)
 [1] 7.47456e-25
 > L0(10)
 [1] 7.694599e-23
```

As the OP further asked for the *inverse* function as well, @Ben Bolker showed the standard solution via root finding,

```
 Linv <- function(y) uniroot(function(x) L(x) - y, interval=c(-10,10))$root
```

which works in good cases, if the argument is of length 1. OTOH, if `Linv` itself should
vectorize, and if you want it and `L(.)` to also work for boundary cases, there are some tricks and speedups one can do.

---> Nice extended answer on rpubs:  http://rpubs.com/maechler/16436

Comment: @MarinMächler thanks for your answer. In fact I dont see any difference in the output of the `L`and `L0`functions if I use the z values from my table which range from -3.00 to 3.00. But if you say it is more accurate, i might as well use your `L` function

Comment: In that range you *might* see a difference if you `print(result,digits=20)` but otherwise not.

Comment: @BenBolker @MartinMächler @GavinKelly I was able to solve the initial problem, but now I need to find the inverse function of `L`. I tried to define a function that computes L^-1 but that is clearly not correct. so is there a function i could use to determine z, given the standard normal loss function (in the example above: a function that takes `0.0026`as input and returns `2.42`)? thanks

Comment: Your question is right on the edge of being worth asking as a separate question.  Unless it turns out to be simple to do the algebra of inverting `y=dnorm(x)-x*pnorm(x,lower.tail=FALSE)`, you might be forced to use something like `Linv <- function(z) uniroot(function(x) L(x)-z, interval=c(-10,10))$root` ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks a lot! your `Linv` actually works (and, sadly, i wouldn't have been able to figure out this solution)

Comment: maybe Martin or Gavin will be willing to incorporate the `Linv()` solution into their answers ...

Comment: I just did ... including a link to a fast and "fool proof" version of L() and Linv()

Comment: @MartinMächler thanks for the explanation and link to the extended answer

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the standard normal loss function, then:

```
L <- function(x)  exp(-(x^2)/2)/(sqrt(2*pi)) - x*(1-pnorm(x))
L(2.42)
```

appears to agree with your value